# Getting element content with JSOUP node's attributes

Tags: java, html

I'm having troubles with JSoup.

I have this html code:

```
 <div title = "test" data-x="test1">I am the content</div>
```

I'm using Jsoup to parse the html file.

When I'm traversing it like this:

```
html.traverse(new NodeVisitor() {
        public void head(Node node, int depth) {
            System.out.println(node.attributes());

        }

        public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
            ...
        }
   });
```

I can see with the print that Jsoup assumes Element content is an attribute. Is that right? 
I was expecting to get only "title" and "data-x" in this example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String html = "<div title = 'test' data-x='test1'>I am the content</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element div = doc.select("div").first();

String divTitle = div.attr("title"); // "test"
String divDataX = div.attr("data-x"); // "test1"
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't make it static. I need to iterate node's attributes

Answer (score 0):

When you traverse some node, NodeVisitor access its content as well, considering it a child node of text type. You can filter out node attributes using depth variable.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data);
    doc.getElementsByTag("div").traverse(new NodeVisitor() {

        public void head(Node node, int depth) {
            System.out.println(depth + ":" + node.attributes());
        }

        public void tail(Node node, int depth) {

        }
    });
```

Output will be as follows:

```
0: title="test" data-x="test1"
1: #text="I am the content"
```

So inside of head() method add the check for the depth:

```
       public void head(Node node, int depth) {
            if(depth == 0) {
                Attributes attributes = node.attributes();
                // handle attributes
            }
        }
```